# Beginning with SDRs, recommendations

Tags: discussion

I am looking to venture into SDRs for educational purposes and getting some practical hands on experience with them. Any pointers to how I can start,

1. which texts/tutorials? 
   which softwares to use?
   which Hardwares to use?

Answer (score 1):

The first question (which texts/tutorials?) can probably be safely asked on the main site provided you tag it with <kbd>reference-request</kbd>.

Regarding software, your best bet is to ask [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

And you really need to expand upon the hardware request... that's such an open-ended question I'm not sure where to start. ;-)